# Code that allows User to access folders AND file details

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scripting, policies

I have 2 snippets of code for Amazon's AWS S3 storage area. One allows access to certain User folders only, but does not allow the user to see the file/img details for some reason. When I add the 2nd snippet I found it allows the User to see the file/img details, but then also gives the User access to folders I don't want them to have access to. I've tried to rearrange this a million ways but cannot get them to mesh. Can anyone help with this?

Here is Code Block 1:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::tp-new-aframe-displays"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "tp-User-1/"
                    ],
                    "s3:delimiter": [
                        "/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::tp-new-aframe-displays"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "tp-User-1/${aws:username}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::tp-new-aframe-displays/tp-User-1/${aws:username}/*"
            ]
        }
]
}
```

And here is code block 2:

```
{
            "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::tp-new-aframe-displays"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::tp-new-aframe-displays/tp-User-1/${aws:username}/*"
            ]
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm not an expert programmer, but I'm good enough to be "dangerous".

I need access to the red circled area. The highlight is a button that copies the link.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhXef.png)

Shows the 3 User folders I created that will be changed to specific user names at some point.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rv8h.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "but does not allow the user to see the file/img details"?

Comment: In AWS's S3 storage area when you upload an image to store you can click on it and see info like it's link location for others to find when using them as displays for product images on the various online selling platforms. I need the User to have access to that screen to get the link.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Please Edit your question to show the specific problem with your first configuration (eg a screenshot of what is failing). Your second code set should _not_ be granting access to any other 'folders', so that is most strange. I used your first example on my own bucket and the user with those permissions is able to access the folder as expected and view _most_ information about the object (but not Versioning and Tags).

Comment: OK I have screenshot a few images of what is happening. I also see some errors in the Visual Editor tab of the Policy area, but none on the JSON tab where the code is. So maybe that is a focus also. I don't see where I/how I can add screenshots to my posts. How would I do that? There is no attachment or upload link that I see.